# How do I fix Nginx config to work with multiple hosts of Unicorn?

Tags: nginx, configuration, unicorn

I have no problem instantiating multiple instances of unicorn on different unix sockets and ports.  Works fine if I do url:port.

My problem comes in correctly formatting nginx.conf to allow multipe upstream conditions.
Whatever i do does not seem to work.  One instance is fine works fine. Multiple gives me a  ""upstream" directive is not allowed here error

I am using the base nginx sample from the unicorn site.  and doubling up the upstream area with differing terms.  each is part of the http set.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Could you provide the nginx config here so we don't have to go search the unicorn site for it?

Comment: @Martin Fjordvald [saved you a search](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/examples/nginx.conf)

Comment: Indeed. A year and some later, but appreciated none the less. Regardless, some modification must have taken place for the question to make any sense at all. Otherwise he's asking not how to fix a problem but rather for someone to do his work for him so he doesn't need to understand the software he uses.

Answer (score 1):

Your upstream definitions must live outside of http {} or server {} definitions.

Comment: and you use your upstream in your `server` definition, like `proxy_pass http://my_upstream`